# Excel: How to duplicate without some specified cells?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2011

So basically, I want to create a hyperlink on one of my worksheets that allows me to duplicate it exactly, without a few cells.

I found this on the Microsoft Support website that allows a worksheet to do duplicated exactly:

```
Sub Copier1()
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Copy _
       after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice")
End Sub
```

For a better example, I am making an invoice generator. I can enter prices and products, along with calculating totals. I am trying to make a simple button that creates a new invoice in a new worksheet that is blank, along with making my invoice number go up by 1.

The cells with the transparent red are the ones that should not be copied. Although, they contain formulas that should be copied. Is there maybe a way to copy the full worksheet while 'resetting' it and adding the invoice number by 1? **All cells that need to be 'reset' can be hardcoded within the macro since the invoice layout will always be the same.**

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You don't seem to have too much VBA knowledge, not even the ideas too clear regarding what you want to do and perhaps you should work on both fronts before asking. An example to understand this: imagine that you want to copy all the cells except "A1", "B3" and "B4"; doing that is easy (similar size to the one of the code you posted); but then you will want to select this cells dynamically, for example, by clicking on them and thus you would have to learn to deal with that; and then you would want a variable-number of cells to be skipped and thus you will have to learn this too...

Comment: ... apparently you have some web experience: what would be your answer to a question of someone (with no web experience) asking for the way to "build a web with buttons, which open things and store information and all this"?

Comment: @varocarbas - That is correct, I have near to no experience with VBA. Although, if someone asked such as question in lets say, PHP, it would be something simple such as "How to copy the contents of a webpage". Something like that would be just a few lines, and they would not be criticised here on SO. I never use Excel, and I was just curious on how to do this since I am making a small invoice generator for my new store. If the answer is only 2-3 lines, whats the harm of providing an example since you seem to already know the answer? This could be beneficial for other users searching for this.

Comment: Your question in PHP? "I want a script able to open a file and copy certain parts of it"; note that the important bit in this question is "CERTAIN PARTS". How you want to select the parts? How many parts? How big is each part, etc. Copying all the contents of a file in PHP is straightforward (as in VBA); doing what you want is, at least, unclear and, in the best scenario, not straightforward. If you want hints, make your ideas clearer ("I want a maximum of 100 exceptional cells; I want the user to select these cells by doing this; I want, etc.").

Comment: It seems that you are not a novice user of SO and thus you should know all this: nobody will deliver here a working code for you under these conditions (poor knowledge, poor description and no effort by your own). If you want hints, be much more clear as suggested.

Comment: @varocarbas - My apologies, rushed through the question without providing enough for any user to determine what I was after. Added some more info to my question, along with an image for reference.

Comment: See? This is a completely different story. Much better; but still you are not clarifying how the selection is expected to occur: will the cells be hardcoded or shall the user select which ones he wants? In case that the user will perform the selection, how are you planning to do that? By background colors, by selecting ranges? etc.

Comment: Explain all this clearly in your question and you will get help quickly (not from me because it is a bit late here and will go to bed in brief).

Comment: @varocarbas - Thanks for that. Edited my question once again and it seems to contain all the information I am after. Cheers.

Comment: @fizzix thanks for the update! The specifics help a lot.

Comment: where do the formulas point too? same workbook, Database, different workbook.  How are the formulas updated?

Comment: @Sorceri - Sorry, got to break that down a little. Extremely new to VBA and Excel. Everything is inside the same Excel Document if that helps. Nothing external.

Comment: @Sorceri - The formulas within the cells are just basic things such as `VLOOKUP` and `SUM`. They are only updated when other cells are changed.

Comment: so the question is what cells do you enter data in, if they are just lookup cells then we should be able to just copy the sheet and clear the cells you enter in the data.  All other cells should update once you update the lookup table....unless I am still missing something

Comment: @Sorceri - Yes that is completely right

Comment: @fizzix  so which cells?  I would assume just the lower portion and the invoice number need to be cleared....but confirm.

Comment: @Sorceri - Check the comment I added in response to your comment to Blackhawks answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This copies the worksheet and then clears out the product info

```
Sub createNewInvoice()
'this assumes the top portion of the invoice never changes
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim startCol As Integer
Dim invNumber As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim invCol As Integer
Dim invRow As Integer

invRow = 8
invCol = 6 'F column
startRow = 18 '18 is the first line of items
startCol = 2 'B

'get the invoice number
invNumber = CInt(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Cells(invRow, invCol).Value)
'set the worksheet object
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice")
'copy after invoice
ws.Copy After:=ws

'update our invoice number
ws.Cells(invRow, invCol).Value = invNumber + 1
'make the worksheet active
ws.Activate
'clear out our cells with the product info
'clear the first line and delete the rest
Do While Trim(ws.Cells(startRow, startCol).Value) <> ""
    If startRow = 18 Then
        ws.Cells(startRow, startCol).EntireRow.ClearContents
    Else
        ws.Cells(startRow, startCol).EntireRow.Delete shift:=Excel.xlShiftUp
        'reset the row
        startRow = startRow - 1
    End If
    'move to the next row
    startRow = startRow + 1
Loop

'release the worksheet object
Set ws = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a ways to go before you will have a usable system, but here is an example of how to do what you are asking.  Note that a lot of this is very manual (all the `Range` stuff) and that makes it dangerous - if you ever rearrange things on the sheet, you would have to modify the code accordingly.  I would strongly recommend Access for such a task, it is well worth the learning curve.  Also, I didn't do it below, but you may want to change the name of the new sheet.

```
Public Sub NewInvoice()
    Dim wksht As Worksheet
    Dim newwksht As Worksheet

    'Copy the Invoice worksheet
    Set wksht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice")
    wksht.Copy after:=wksht

    'The new worksheet is active, get a reference to it
    Set newwksht = ActiveSheet

    With newwksht
        'Clear all the input cells

        'Customer Info
        .Range("C7:C13").Value = ""

        'Company/Date
        .Range("F7").Value = ""
        .Range("F8").Value = .Range("F8").Value + 1 'Increment Invoice Number
        .Range("F9").Value = ""

        'Upper left Product # all the way to the lower right Line Total, however many there might be.
        .Range(.Range("B18"), .Range("B18").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Value = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Blackhawk :) Although, I am receiving an error on this line: `.Range("F8").Value = .Range("F8").Value + 1 'Increment Invoice Number`. Any idea why?

Comment: Figured it out. Didn't like the comment on the same line as the code. Seems to be deleting all of my formulas form these cells though. Is there a way around this?

Comment: look at my question would be your answer ;)  you are thinking to much here. What oyu want is really simple, just which cells do not contain formulas as those are the only ones that need to be cleared.  All other cells use a lookup so we do not need to touch them. Also is the invoice number a lookup?

Comment: @Sorceri - All cells (besides just a few) with the red transparent box around them in my example image contain formulas such as `SUM` and `VLOOKUP`, and they are the ones that need to be reset. The `Invoice Number` is just a number entered directly into the cell.

Comment: @Sorceri - Would `Record Macro` be the best answer for this?

Comment: so Net GST and Grand Total are sum fields, The top portion except the invoice number are lookups, what about the product lines, are those lookups, do you add an line each time?  I will post an answer here in about 5 minutes with the assumtion that everything under Product #, Quantity, Desc, Unit Price, Line total are entered in.   If any one of these cells has a formula please let me know.  The way you describe it is all cells have formulas as All i see is red cells were data should go, no transparent red outline ect (at least I do not see them)...hence why I keep asking which cells